# upgrading from rxjs v5.5.6 to rxjs v6.3.3 with rxjs-compat v6.3.3

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rxjs6

So i just recently began updating the version of rxjs on my react project, following the instructions given here: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration

according to the instructions everything should work as normal with the compatibility layer installed as well. The 'breaking changes not covered by rxjs-compat' are not relevant to my project.

all I have done is run the command `npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save` and now i get the following error when trying to run my site:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'bindCallback' of undefined
at Object.defineProperty.value (bindCallback.js:4)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap aec2a29d759a238a1d9d:54)
at Object.__webpack_exports__.a (Rx.js:17)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap aec2a29d759a238a1d9d:54)
at Object.defineProperty.value (Rx.js:6)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap aec2a29d759a238a1d9d:54)
at Object.defineProperty.value (Subject.js:3)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap aec2a29d759a238a1d9d:54)
at Object.module.exports (Subject.js:6)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap aec2a29d759a238a1d9d:54)
```

Can anybody help me with this? I have done a lot of research but most sources seem to cover angular rather than react, also everywhere seems to declare that all old syntax and imports should run fine

extra note: if I update the syntax and imports to those associated with rxjs 6 alone, everthing works fine, but as rxjs themselves say, it should work fine with old syntax (so long as rxjs-compat is installed), and i want to keep the old syntax for now so that things can be introduced and tested step by step.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to import `bindCallback` like following:

```
import { bindCallback } from "rxjs";
```